# How to get "ldconfig"?

Tags: command, ldconfig

I am trying setup wireless network.

I referred to [Cross Compiling iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill for ARM](http://wiki.beyondlogic.org/index.php?title=Cross_Compiling_iw_wpa_supplicant_hostapd_rfkill_for_ARM).

In the `iw` part, he used `ldconfig -v`, but it is not in my rootfs.
I searched my busybox, but could not find it.

How to get the `ldconfig` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ldconfig` is a part of **libc** (C library). In various distros name of the package may vary, for instance:

```
[yurij@centos7 gpg]$ rpm -qf /usr/sbin/ldconfig
glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64

yurij@debian9:~/trash/gpg$ dpkg -S /sbin/ldconfig
libc-bin: /sbin/ldconfig
```

So in Centos 7 it's **glibc** package, in Debian - **libc-bin**.

Indeed you can get can source of **glibc** - [glibc official site](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/sources.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am compiling it for my system. I chose the version v2.11, and completed build. But I need to reduce the size of binaries. I don't know what the option is to reduce size(without debug symbols). Let me know how please.

Comment: It's depend on compiler and therefore compile options. I will show you examples about `gcc`. At first, you can enable `-O3` flag for general optimisation. Secondly, you can disable LTO (Link Time Optimisation) `-fno-lto`. It's useful feature but it enlarge produced binaries. Also you need ensure that you have disabled debug symbols.

Comment: Thanks, I checked the non-debug info by using command "readelf -S". But, I have to reduce a bit more. I will test more.